# Is there a way to create a python script that is constantly clicking on a link?

Tags: python, hyperlink

There's just this article in a webpage newspaper and I wanted to make an algorithm that constantly clicks by using requests or another import to make it more popular. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look into selenium. It is used for web browser automation. The benefit of that it is like a real user and also runs javascript. Else if you figured out how the counting mechanism works you can directly hit the endpoint. All in all this is not a code writing service, you are supposed to show code and be specific where you are stuck at. Furthermore it's not a great start asking for something controversial.

Comment: Asking here is not considered research.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course click a lot of times on a button with python
you just need a loop, and an action that "clicks"

Nevertheless, I'm not sure if it is going to be efficient for what you want : search engines like google probably doesn't count the requests coming from bots

Comment: Your question is a bit general in that it completely leaves out the fact that your program needs to talk to a browser. I suggest you look at 'Selenium' which will provide a framework to do this kind of thing.